# Select ,option do something

Tags: html, html-select

I want to do when click on vault1 ..vault5 do something

```
<form id="someform">

    <select id="selectid">
        <option selected="selected">Choose Vault</option>
        <option value="1"> Vault 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> Vault 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> Vault 3 </option>
        <option value="4"> Vault 4 </option>
        <option value="5"> Vault 5 </option>
    </select>

</form>

if value == 1 { do something} .... if value== 5 { do something}
```

Comment: You may want to look into JavaScript. It's a programming language that runs in the browser, it allows you do this kind of thing. Or you are looking for a server side language. In its current form, this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, though.

Answer (score 0):

when "Do something" must to use mssql query